# Github actions with `github` protocol in `npm ci`

Tags: node.js, github, npm, continuous-integration

Here's my `node.js.yml`:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x, 16.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm test
```

In my `package.json` I have a dependency on `uWebSockets.js` as following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    // (...)
    "uWebSockets.js": "github:uNetworking/uWebSockets.js#v20.10.0",
    // (...)
  }
```

Now when the github action runs, on `npm ci` step I get the following output:

```
Run npm ci
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-08-12T11_55_19_355Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have no clue what to change to make it work. Removing `github:` protocol explicit definition in `package.json` makes the library not install correctly in non-CI environment.

Thanks

Comment: The solution was the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69634515/npm-err-gitgithub-com-permission-denied-publickey-in-github-action

Comment: It seems that's not the solution, it has to be via git protocol. I need an answer to the original question